# Add composite primary key to sql result

Tags: java, mysql, composite-primary-key

I am trying to create a mysql queryer in java and I would like to be able to add the primary key(composite) associated with the user query.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE logic
```

How can i add the composite primary key as the first column of my result? I need to keep columns asked by the user too.

Do i need to use:
 `CONCAT_WS('-',column1,column2,column3) ?`

I can't use it if the user asks every columns (using *).

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  If one selects `*` then all columns are returned, including those over which keys (such as composite primary keys) are defined.

Comment: yes but i can't know the order of columns asked (if user choose to not display all columns) and what if the user join 2 tables?

Comment: "Users" who write SQL will know how they want their results: either your application should not permit users to write SQL, or you should not be trying to manipulate the results they obtain.  What is the wider context of this problem?

Comment: I display the result on a web page. I need to create a link on each row that permit to show associated mytable2 data filtered by primary key. There is a 1-n relationship between two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will help:

SELECT concat(....), mytable.* 
FROM mytable

Although when you add the concat-column add the end, somthing like below without the additional table reference should work fine:

SELECT *, concat(....) FROM mytable